# In SP 2013, we are able to see the output printed in one single line even though we have entered in different lines in the rich text field of a list

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, rich-text

In SharePoint 2013, when we enter values for a Rich text field of a list in different lines and when the document is generated , we observe that all the data is obtained in one single line. 
This is developed through custom code using Visual Studio. It is working as expected in SharePoint 2010 environment.
Once it is migrated to SharePoint 2013 environment we are facing this issue.

Can anyone please help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my SharePoint 2013 environment with SP1(15.0.4569.1000), the values are returned as multiple lines when the values were in different lines.
[image]

Check your farm's build number, make sure it is or after SP1.
[SharePoint Patches](https://sharepointupdates.com/Patches)